# How to iterate over string after using split function

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

Here is the string 
ds = 'Java; Python; Ruby; SQL'
I have used slip function to split each language and found the count of one language.
if I want to find if any of 2 languages occur in a string it's returning zero.
example: in the above variable as both java and python are present it has to return count as one.

```
def language_both_jp(y):
    count = 0
    prog = (y.split(";"))
    for i in range(0,len(prog)):
        if(prog[i] == 'Java'):
            for i in range(0,len(prog)):
                if(prog[i] == 'Python'):
                    count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What if "Java" is present twice? What should be the count then? Also, you might want to read up on the basics of looping in python

Answer (score 3):

You could so something like this, instead use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to store the counts of each language:

```
ds = 'Java; Python; Ruby; SQL'

counts = {}
for chunk in ds.split(';'):
    language = chunk.strip()
    counts[language] = counts.get(language, 0) + 1

print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
{'Java': 1, 'SQL': 1, 'Python': 1, 'Ruby': 1}
```

A more *pythonic* approach will be to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

ds = 'Java; Python; Ruby; SQL'
counts = Counter(language.strip() for language in ds.split(';'))
print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'Java': 1, 'Ruby': 1, 'Python': 1, 'SQL': 1})
```

Once you have a mapping-like object with the counts of each language, iterate over the key, value pairs and output those with count above 1, for example:

```
from collections import Counter

ds = 'Java; Python; Ruby; SQL; Python'
counts = Counter(language.strip() for language in ds.split(';'))

for language, count in counts.items():
    if count > 1:
        print(language, count)
```

**Output**

```
Python 2
```

Note that the input string in the above example was slightly modified to include Python twice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should be splitting by `"; "`, so you should have:

```
def language_both_jp(y):
    count = 0
    prog = (y.split("; "))
    for i in range(0,len(prog)):
        if(prog[i] == 'Java'):
            for i in range(0,len(prog)):
                if(prog[i] == 'Python'):
                    count += 1
    return count

language_both_jp(ds)
#1
```

A simpler approach would be:

```
def language_both_jp(x, l):
    return 1 if [i for i in ds.split("; ") if i in l] else 0

language_both_jp(ds, ['Python','Java'])
#1
```

Answer (score 0):

your requirement is not clearly understandable...
however please try below solutions...

`i`. if you `want to find the count of occurrence` of a `word` just pass the string and the `word`as argument..

try below code...

```
def language_both_jp(y, word):
    count = 0
    prog = (y.split(";"))
    for i in range(0,len(prog)):
        if(prog[i] == word):
            count += 1
return count

string = 'java;python;java;python;c;python'
print(language_both_jp(string, 'java'))
```

it will print the count of occurrence of the word

`ii`. If you want to fine the occurrence of two words..

try below code..

```
def language_both_jp(y, word1,word2):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    prog = (y.split(";"))
    for i in range(0,len(prog)):
        if(prog[i] == word1):
            count1 += 1
        if(prog[i] == word2):
            count2 += 1
    return 'occurrence of '+word1+'='+str(count1)+'\n'+'occurrence of '+word2+'='+str(count2)

args = 'java;python;java;python;c;python'
print(language_both_jp(args, 'java','python'))
```

`iii`. If you want to find the presence of any two words...

try below code

```
def language_both_jp(y, word1,word2):
    count = ''
    prog = (y.split(";"))
    for i in range(0,len(prog)):
        if(prog[i] == word1):
            for i in range(0, len(prog)):
                if(prog[i] == word2):
                    count = 'yes'
                else:
                    count = 'no'
return count

args = 'java;python;java;python;c;python'
print(language_both_jp(args, 'java','python'))
```

please ask if you have any doubts...